# Block 4g when WiFi is available, and limit access to programs

Tags: wi-fi, 4g, firewall

What's the best way to config it? If WiFi is available, 4g remains locked.

When WiFi isn't available, use 4g, but only for Watsupp and no video.

Comment: If your device is rooted, you could try [Smart Network](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.smartnetwork) or have a look at [tag:automation] tag for other means

Comment: Thanks, but Google play said that Smart Network isn't available in my country :/